# Using pandas groupby to create new dataframe containing all columns of parent dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

EDIT: REWROTE ENTIRE QUESTION

I've written a program that matches a list of **store** locations with another list of **doctor** locations based on *longitude and latitude*.

Each store location possesses a unique ID. I'd like to find the 3 rows for each unique ID (unit, in this case) with the smallest distance value. I'd like these rows to contain all the information in the original df.

Using this statement I am able to find the unit numbers and their corresponding distance, but nothing else.

```
df.groupby(['unit'])['distance'].nsmallest(3)
```

Example original dataframe

```
unit      store_name      distance     doctor_name
123       taqueria         0.3          dr. a
123       taqueria         0.35         dr. b
123       taqueria         0.2          dr. c
123       taqueria       0.5          dr. smith
123       taqueria       0.4          dr. q
123       taqueria       0.1          dr. who
456       carniceria         0.5          dr. a
456       carniceria         0.6         dr. b
456       carniceria         0.3          dr. c
456       carniceria       0.1         dr. smith
456       carniceria       0.2          dr. q
456       carniceria       0.05          dr. who
```

Intended output

```
unit      store_name      distance     doctor_name
123       taqueria         0.3          dr. a
123       taqueria         0.2          dr. c
123       taqueria       0.1          dr. who
456       carniceria       0.1         dr. smith
456       carniceria       0.2          dr. q
456       carniceria       0.05          dr. who
```

The intended output would reduce the dataframe to the three **closest** doctor_names grouped by unit

Comment: Can you provide the sample input?

Comment: show original df please

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga dmitry-polonskiy added in the original column headers.

Comment: No, I don't need the column names, you need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. In the case of `pandas` questions, that involves an example input dataframe with the output you expect.

Comment: @TrevorBurke you could use  `df.head(n=10).to_dict()` to provide a sample input that can be used to help you with a solution.

Comment: ok, i created a dummy version of what the original dataframe looks like and what I hope the output to look like...

Comment: @muon see edit, thanks

Answer (score 3):

## `pandas`

*fuzzy and lovable, also pretty quick*

```
df.sort_values(['unit', 'distance']).groupby('unit').head(3)

    unit  store_name  distance doctor_name
5    123    taqueria      0.10     dr. who
2    123    taqueria      0.20       dr. c
0    123    taqueria      0.30       dr. a
11   456  carniceria      0.05     dr. who
9    456  carniceria      0.10   dr. smith
10   456  carniceria      0.20       dr. q
```

## `numpy`

*quick*

```
v = df.values
u = df.unit.values
d = df.distance.values
s = d.size
r = np.arange(s)
a = np.lexsort([d, u])
u2 = u[a]

b = (np.where(np.append(True, u2[1:] != u2[:-1]))[0])
delta = np.diff(np.append(b, s))
mask = ((r - b.repeat(delta)) < 3)
pd.DataFrame(v[a][mask], df.index[a][mask], df.columns)

   unit  store_name distance doctor_name
5   123    taqueria      0.1     dr. who
2   123    taqueria      0.2       dr. c
0   123    taqueria      0.3       dr. a
11  456  carniceria     0.05     dr. who
9   456  carniceria      0.1   dr. smith
10  456  carniceria      0.2       dr. q
```

---

***timing small data***

[image]

***timing large data***

[image]
    ​

Comment: Ah! Trick no 2:)

Comment: @A-Za-z I'm doing a full sort which isn't necessary.  Some method with `nsmallest` should be better.  This just looks cooler.  I'm putting together a quicker one and will show timings.  This definitely is understandable though.

Comment: @piRSquared curious to see the optimized version, as well!

Comment: Optimized attempt number one is not as quick as this.  This is pretty fast.  Going deep on this one.  Going full numpy, we'll see what happens.

Comment: @TrevorBurke got something quicker.  But not nearly as pretty.

Comment: @piRSquared this is pretty sweet. makes me want to get into numpy more (and learn cython haha)

Answer (score 1):

Use set_index() first

```
df = df.set_index(['store_name', 'doctor_name'])    
df1 = df.groupby(['unit'])['distance'].nsmallest(3).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    unit    store_name  doctor_name distance
0   123     taqueria    dr.who      0.10
1   123     taqueria    dr.c        0.20
2   123     taqueria    dr.a        0.30
3   456     carniceria  dr.who      0.05
4   456     carniceria  dr.smith    0.10
5   456     carniceria  dr.q        0.20
```

Comment: that is perfect